# Machine learning frameworks for esoteric languages

Tags: machine-learning, programming-languages, resource-request

Is there a machine learning framework/library for any of the esoteric languages, such as the ones listed [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) ?

Comment: Why would you want to develop machine learning software in an esoteric language?

Comment: I dont want to. Im curious if someone else did.

Comment: I haven't yet found any machine learning library written with an esoteric language, but I found a [tic-tac-toe program written in Brainfuck](https://github.com/mitxela/bf-tic-tac-toe). See also [https://mitxela.com/projects/ai_in_brainfuck](https://mitxela.com/projects/ai_in_brainfuck).

Comment: [Questions asking for tools, such as software libraries or APIs, are off-topic here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We focus on the **theoretical, social** and **philosophical** aspects of artificial intelligence (so this excludes recommendations of software libraries). If you have again this type of question in the future, you should ask it here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/